# Pre-populating DateField in Django REST Framework Serializer Not Working

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I am developing a web application using Django and Django REST Framework. I have a serializer with a date field that I want to pre-populate with the current date when the form is displayed.
The [rest framework documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#initial) demonstrate how to use `initial` to pre-populate a field, but it doesn't seems to be working. Despite following the documentation, the date field of my form displays "yyyy-mm-dd".

Environment:
django==3.2.18
djangorestframework==3.14.0

Here is my current code:

```
# serializer.py
class FormSerializerCurrentStatus(ModelSerializer):
    date = serializers.DateField(initial=datetime.date.today)

    class Meta:
        model = CurrentStatus
        fields = ('date', 'user', 'currentstatus')

# views.py
def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form_serializer = FormSerializerCurrentStatus()
    return Response({'serializer': form_serializer})

# html
<form action="{% url 'SomeUrl' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% render_form serializer %}
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

I have also attempted to override the **init** method of the serializer to set the initial value of the date field.

Does anyone could help me understand what my mistake might be?
Thank you!